# Filter with two id of the same value CPT UI(taxanomies)

Tags: custom-taxonomy, filters, search, request-filter

I have a special link with a filter, so I filter things with slugs through the link, for example

```
mydomain.com/filter/?technology=angular&category=software-development
```

and it shows the chosen jobs

Now, I want to show jobs with different id's but with the same slug, like here:

```
mydomain.com/filter/?bullhorn_id=2979,2090
```

I tried this variation

```
https://itds.pl/filter/?bullhorn_id=2979&bullhorn_id=2903
```

and it's not working
With one ID it works perfectly
Could please someone help me? I'm not good in PHP
here is part of a code that generates link

```
 if(isset($_GET['bullhorn_id'])){
                        $bullhorn = explode(',',$_GET['bullhorn_id']);
                        if(count($bullhorn)>=0){                                
                            for($p=0;$p<count($bullhorn);$p++){                                  
                                $filter[] = array( 'taxonomy' => 'bullhorn_id', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $bullhorn[$p]  );
                            } 
                        }
                        else{
                            $filter[] = array( 'taxonomy' => 'bullhorn_id', 'field' => 'slug', 'terms' => $_GET['bullhorn_id']  );
                        }
                    }
```

Oh and BTW it's taxonomy, and the costume template for the page
The QUERY is in the function and looks like this:

```
     // Filter for search query
    if(isset($_REQUEST['input_keyword']) && $_REQUEST['input_keyword']!=''){
        $arg['s'] = $_REQUEST['input_keyword'];
    }
    
    // Set meta query with argument
    if(isset($_REQUEST['location']) && $_REQUEST['location']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'location',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['location']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['technology']) && $_REQUEST['technology']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'technology',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['technology']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['product_category']) && $_REQUEST['product_category']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['product_category']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['employment_type']) && $_REQUEST['employment_type']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'employment_type',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['employment_type']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['seniority']) && $_REQUEST['seniority']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'seniority',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['seniority']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['type_of_work']) && $_REQUEST['type_of_work']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'type_of_work',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['type_of_work']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['language']) && $_REQUEST['language']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'language',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['language']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['skills']) && $_REQUEST['skills']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'skills',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['skills']
            );
    }
if(isset($_REQUEST['bullhorn_id']) && $_REQUEST['bullhorn_id']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'bullhorn_id',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['bullhorn_id']
            );
    }
    if(isset($_REQUEST['hot_offer']) && $_REQUEST['hot_offer']!=''){
        $filter[] = array (
                'taxonomy' => 'hot_offer',
                'field' => 'slug',
                'terms' => $_REQUEST['hot_offer']
            );
    }
    if( !empty($filter) && count($filter)>1 ){
        $arg['tax_query'] = $filter;   
    }
          
  
    if(isset($_REQUEST['max_price']) && $_REQUEST['max_price']!=''){
      
  
             $filtermeta[] = array(
                'key' => 'maximum_price',
                'value' => array(trim($_REQUEST['max_price']), 1000000),
                'compare' => 'BETWEEN',
                'type' => 'numeric'
            );      
    }

    if( !empty($filtermeta) && count($filtermeta)>1 ){
        $arg['meta_query'] = $filtermeta;   
    }
```

Comment: It looks like you have `/filter/` set up as a Page with a custom page template. If that's true, then the main query is already dedicated to fetching that page - are you performing a secondary query to fetch the other posts? If so, how is it using the URL query parameters? Or is a plugin facilitating this sort of functionality?

Comment: Hello @bosco! Yes, it has a custom template. The QUERY in function file and I will add how it looks in the post, see, please
so basically it fetch the data from product taxonomy and filtering it
It's not generating a links itself so I writhing it bymyself, so if I need category I add ?category=it in the end of a link and it shows the data, so I don't know how to make it show few values of the same taxonomy :(